# stringindexoutofbounds with currency converter java program

Tags: java

I am have trouble with a summary not showing up. I am supposed to modify a previous Java assignment by by adding an array of objects.  Within the loop, instantiate each individual object.   Make sure the user cannot keep adding another Foreign conversion beyond your array size.
    After the user selects quit from the menu, prompt if the user want to display a summary report.  If they select ‘Y’ then, using your array of objects, display the following report:

```
Item     Conversion       Dollars     Amount  
 1       Japanese Yen     100.00    32,000.00   
 2       Mexican Peso     400.00    56,000.00  
 3       Canadian Dollar  100.00     156.00
```

etc.

Number of Conversions = 3

There are no errors when I compile..but when I run the program it is fine until I hit 0 to end the conversion and have it ask if i want to see a summary. This error displays:

Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
        at Lab8.main(Lab8.java:43)

my code:

> ```
> import java.util.Scanner;
> import java.text.DecimalFormat;
>
> public class Lab8
> {
>     public static void main(String[] args)
>     {
>         final int Max = 10;
>         String a;
>         char summary;
>         int c = 0;
>       Foreign[] Exchange = new Foreign[Max];
>       Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
>
>       Foreign.opening();
>
>         do
>         {
>          Exchange[c] = new Foreign();
>            Exchange[c].getchoice();
>          Exchange[c].dollars();
>          Exchange[c].amount();
>          Exchange[c].vertical();
>          System.out.println("\n" + Exchange[c]);
>          c++;
>
>   System.out.println("\n" + "Please select 1 through 4, or 0 to quit" + >"\n");
>          c= Keyboard.nextInt();
>
>         }
>           while (c != 0);
>
>
>         System.out.print("\nWould you like a summary of your conversions? (Y/N): ");
>               a = Keyboard.nextLine();
>               summary = a.charAt(0);
>               summary = Character.toUpperCase(summary);
>
>       if (summary == 'Y')
>               {
>       System.out.println("\nCountry\t\tRate\t\tDollars\t\tAmount");
>                  System.out.println("========\t\t=======\t\t=======\t\t=========");
>         for (int i=0; i < Exchange.length; i++)
>         System.out.println(Exchange[i]);
>
>           Foreign.counter();
>           }
>     }
> }
> ```

I looked at line 43 and its this line: summary = a.charAt(0);

But I am not sure what's wrong with it, can anyone point it out? Thank you.

Comment: Well, what have you tried? apparently, the string `a` is an empty string when you reach line 43.

Comment: did you enter a blank line ? like just pressed enter ?

Comment: Just a comment on style: I'd encourage you to follow the Java Code Coventions (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html)... specifically: `thisIsAVariableName`, and `ThisIsAClassName`... and I'd also make `MAX_EXCHANGES` a constant instead of a local `Max` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not exactly with that line, rather with the last line of the previous while.
You have read your `int` using: -

```
c= Keyboard.nextInt();
```

If you see the documentation of [`Scanner#nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method, it reads the next token from the user input. So, when you pass an integer value, then the `linefeed` at the end which is also passed as a result of you pressing `enter` is not read by `Keyboard.nextInt`, which is then leftover to be read by: -

```
a = Keyboard.nextLine();
```

after the `while` exits. So, basically this statement is reading the left over linefeed by the prevoius `Keyboard.nextInt` call, and thus `a` contains an `empty` string, with a `newline` at the end. And hence you are getting that `Exception`.

**Workaround: -**

You can fire an empty `Keyboard.nextLine` before this statement, which will consume the `linefeed` as its input, so that your next user input starts after it.

```
    // Your code before this while
} while (c != 0);

Keyboard.nextLine();  // Add this line before the next line

System.out.print("\nWould you like a summary of your conversions? (Y/N): ");
a = Keyboard.nextLine();
```

---

**Or, another way** is that you can use `Keyboard.nextLine` to read the integer value also. And then convert it to integer using `Integer.parseInt` method. But be careful, you would have to do some exception handling. So if you still to study about `Exception Handling`, then you can go with the first way.  So, inside your `do-while`, you can do it like this: -

```
try {
    c = Integer.parseInt(Keyboard.nextLine());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: +1 for "don't use nextInt()"... In my experience the whole Scanner class is useless piece of junk, and you're better of just using a BufferedReader.

Comment: @corlettk. Well BufferedReader is better if you don't want to do any parsing with your input, but just read it. But if you want to do some kind of parsing, then Scanner gives you better functionality.

Comment: My point was that Scanner gives you more (but not better) functionality, so that by the time you've actually produced a "usable product" that uses a Scanner you could have just as easily used a basic BufferedReader. See my answer below if you're interested by what I mean by "usable"... My Console class avoids most of "usage pitfalls" of the standard Scanner class, and it's not a lot-of-code really... especially when it's reusable... I use it every-where I need to read keyboard input from a command-line application.

Answer (score 1):

This is common issue. When you use `c= Keyboard.nextInt();`, it reads the `int`. If the return key was pressed during this statement, then `a = Keyboard.nextLine();` will read an empty string as subdue from previous statement in the Input buffer.

You have two options:

1. Add an additional `Keyboard.nextLine();` to cleanup the buffer before reading `a` as `a = Keyboard.nextLine();`
2. If you want to make it full proof to avoid issue in reading empty lines(use presses return key without entering date) then put a while loop as below:

   ```
   a = "";
   while(a.length() <1){
      a = Keyboard.nextLine();
   }
   ```

   This will ensure the `a` has `string length >1`, when it comes out of the loop. With genuine input, it will not do any iterations.

Comment: Good answer, especially the loop to re-read on empty-string... except should that loop should (IMHO) contain an error message (something like "Invalid input, please try again..."). Otherwise the user may think that the software isn't reading there input, when the actual case is there input just can't be processed because it's invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Console class, which I use in place of the Scanner to read keyboard input in command-line applications. Note that class "wraps" the standard java.io.Console, which was introduced in Java 1.6.

You could exhume just the methods you need from my Console class, placing them directly in your `Lab8` class... but I would encourage you to get used to "seperating concerns" into different classes sooner rather than later by creating your own "Keyboard" class, as a cut-down version of my Console.

```
package krc.utilz.io;

import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


/**
 * A static library of helper methods to read keyboard input.
 * <p>
 * <strong>usage:</strong>
 * <code>
 *   import krc.utilz.io.Console;
 *   while ( (score=Console.readInteger("Enter an integer between 0 and 100 (enter to exit) : ", 0, 100, -1)) != -1) { ... }
 * </code>
 */
public abstract class Console
{
  private static final java.io.Console theConsole = System.console();
  static {
    if ( theConsole == null ) {
      System.err.println("krc.utilz.io.Console: No system console!");
      System.exit(2); // 2 traditionally means "system error" on unix.
    }
  }
  private static final DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  private static final DateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

  public static String readString(String prompt) {
    String response = readLine(prompt);
    if(response==null) throw new NullPointerException("response cannot be null");
    return response;
  }

  public static String readLine(String prompt) {
    if (!prompt.endsWith(" ")) prompt += " ";
    System.out.print(prompt);
    return theConsole.readLine();
  }

  public static String readString(String prompt, String regex) {
    while(true) {
      String response = readString(prompt);
      if ( response.length() > 0 ) {
        if ( response.matches(regex) ) {
          return response;
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Oops: A match for "+regex+" is required!");
    }
  }


  public static Date readDate(String prompt) {
    while(true) {
      try {
        return dateFormatter.parse(readString(prompt+" (dd/MM/yyyy) : "));
      } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Oops: "+e);
      }
    }
  }

  public static Date readTime(String prompt) {
    while(true) {
      try {
        String response = readWord(prompt+" (HH:mm:ss) : ");
        return timeFormatter.parse(response);
      } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Oops: "+e);
      }
    }
  }

  public static String readWord(String prompt) {
    while(true) {
      String response = readString(prompt);
      if(response.length()>0 && response.indexOf(' ')<0) return response;
      System.out.println("Oops: A single word is required. No spaces.");
    }
  }

  public static String readWordOrNull(String prompt) {
    while(true) {
      String response = readLine(prompt);
      if(response==null||response.length()==0) return null;
      if(response.indexOf(' ')<0 ) return response;
      System.out.println("Oops: A single word is required. No spaces.");
    }
  }

  public static char readChar(String prompt) {
    while ( true ) {
      String response = readString(prompt);
      if ( response.trim().length() == 1 ) {
        return response.trim().charAt(0);
      }
      System.out.println("Oops: A single non-whitespace character is required!");
    }
  }

  public static char readLetter(String prompt) {
    while(true) {
      String response = readString(prompt);
      if ( response.trim().length() == 1 ) {
        char result = response.trim().charAt(0);
        if(Character.isLetter(result)) return result;
      }
      System.out.println("Oops: A single letter is required!");
    }
  }

  public static char readDigit(String prompt) {
    while(true) {
      String response = readString(prompt);
      if ( response.trim().length() == 1 ) {
        char result = response.trim().charAt(0);
        if(Character.isDigit(result)) return result;
      }
      System.out.println("Oops: A single digit is required!");
    }
  }

  public static int readInteger(String prompt) {
    String response = null;
    while(true) {
      try {
        response = readString(prompt);
        if ( response.length()>0 ) {
          return Integer.parseInt(response);
        }
        System.out.println("An integer is required.");
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Oops \""+response+"\" cannot be interpreted as 32-bit signed integer!");
      }
    }
  }

  public static int readInteger(String prompt, int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    int result = 0;
    while(true) {
      result = readInteger(prompt);
      if ( result>=lowerBound && result<=upperBound ) break;
      System.out.println("An integer between "+lowerBound+" and "+upperBound+" (inclusive) is required.");
    }
    return(result);
  }

  public static int readInteger(String prompt, int defaultValue) {
    String response = null;
    while(true) {
      try {
        response = readString(prompt);
        return response.trim().length()>0 ? Integer.parseInt(response) : defaultValue;
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Oops \""+response+"\" cannot be interpreted as 32-bit signed integer!");
      }
    }
  }

  public static int readInteger(String prompt, int lowerBound, int upperBound, int defaultValue) {
    int result = 0;
    while(true) {
      result = readInteger(prompt, defaultValue);
      if ( result==defaultValue || result>=lowerBound && result<=upperBound ) break;
      System.out.println("An integer between "+lowerBound+" and "+upperBound+" (inclusive) is required.");
    }
    return(result);
  }

  public static double readDouble(String fmt, Object... args) {
    String response = null;
    while(true) {
      try {
        response = System.console().readLine(fmt, args);
        if ( response!=null && response.length()>0 ) {
          return Double.parseDouble(response);
        }
        System.out.println("A number is required.");
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("\""+response+"\" cannot be interpreted as a number!");
      }
    }
  }

  public static double readDouble(String prompt, double lowerBound, double upperBound) {
    while(true) {
      double result = readDouble(prompt);
      if ( result>=lowerBound && result<=upperBound ) {
        return(result);
      }
      System.out.println("A number between "+lowerBound+" and "+upperBound+" (inclusive) is required.");
    }
  }

  public static boolean readBoolean(String prompt) {
    String response = readString(prompt+" (y/N) : ");
    return response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Y");
  }

  public static java.io.Console systemConsole() {
    return theConsole;
  }

}
```

Cheers. Keith.

PS: This gets a LOT easier with practice... you're going well... just keep on truckin.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the great answers, it helped a ton and I learned more than just the solution to the problem. My program works great now! Oh and Keith, thank you for posting some good studying material, especially for newbies like me!